# (ATI Driver Issue) My Mouse Disappears During Game Menu Screens

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon, sony-vaio

I have had this problem since I got this computer in the first place. I have made due mostly by using my other computer for games, or finding games where this doesn't happen. Essentially in most games (all source titles for instance) my mouse won't appear during certain menu screens. Some menu screens work fine. An example would be Counter Strike: GO, during the main menu my mouse appears just fine; however, when I get in game and I need to click the word "GO" to actually start playing I need to guess where it is. During the team fortress 2 main menu this happens as well, but luckily they have tons of buttons and great hover states for their buttons!

I would complain to valve, but this occurs in non-source games as well which makes me think this is a driver issue. I have an ATI graphics card, but when I try to update the drivers from ATI it doesn't let me. I found out that since I have a Sony Vaio I need to go through Sony to get q new driver. Unfortunately, Sony hasn't released a new driver so basically I am out of options. I have tried searching online, but my searches never bring up any sort of answer.

Details:
EB Series Sony Vaio (maybe 2 years old max)
ATI Radeon Graphics Card
Intel i5
4GB RAM

All I am looking for is to be able to see my mouse. I tried setting my computer's mouse settings so that if I press ctrl it would tell me where the mouse is, but that doesn't work in games (for good reason probably).

Comment: When you say ATI doesn't let you, did you run their Driver Verification Tool?

Comment: I mean, when I try to install their driver or the tool that figures out what driver you need it says that I can't install the driver from their site and instead I should check with the computer manufacturer.

Comment: Have you checked for BIOS updates? It may seem an odd way to go but as the graphics chip is integrated into the mainboard, BIOS updates can effect how it works. Alternately, send Sony support a query asking if they have come across this before.

Comment: Forgot to mention, ATI won't offer you a driver for your laptop because the graphics chip is integrated into it in such a way that ATI drivers won't work or will cause more problems than they fix.